# Auto Refresh ASP.NET without blinking page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql-server, ajax

first let me tell you my flow

I want to build seat reservation application(real time).
I use c#, ajax, jquery also sql-server for database.
I have 3 pages
index.html(User Interface), .js(for jQuery , print seat, seat position also bridge for html and aspx), and aspx(which manipulate database)

when you run Index.html you'll see seats, you can click it and input your end time then your seat will change color to red. if current time is equal with your end time then your seat color from red back to green.

seat will change into red when you book it. and your no seat and endTime will insert into DB.
when your endtime = current time -on DB has field status 0 and 1. 0 mean available and 1 mean booked- status change to 0.

it's all done but the color wouldn't back to green. whereas status has change to 0.

this my code in aspx. that get no seat also endtime from .html and .js and also get data from database which seat is still booked.

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static string GetSeat()
    {
        string sql = "";
        SqlConnection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
        conn.Open();
        sql = "UPDATE booking SET statusBooked = 0 WHERE CONVERT(char(5),[end], 108) = '" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm") + "'";
        SqlCommand _cdm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        _cdm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();



        List<booking> bookList = new List<booking>();            
        conn.Open();
        sql = "Select noSeat from booking WHERE statusBooked = 1";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();            
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            booking book = new booking();
            book.noSeat = dr[0].ToString();
            book.end =(DateTime) dr[1];
            bookList.Add(book);

        }      

        conn.Close();

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();            
        return serializer.Serialize(bookList).ToString(); 
    }
```

this is my ajax on .js that receive which seat number is booked and change into red
I put setInterval on document ready. so it will be refresh every 2 second.

```
setInterval('_ajax()', 2000);






function _ajax()
```

{

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Url.aspx/GetSeat",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

    success: function (response) {            
        var arr = JSON.parse(response.d);
        console.log(arr);
        objData = new Array();
        objData = arr;
        for (i = 0; i < objData.length; i++) {
            //console.log(objData[i].noSeat);
            jQuery('#' + objData[i].noSeat).addClass('seat-booked');
            jQuery('#class-' + objData[i].noSeat).attr('value', 'seat-booked');
            jQuery('#' + objData[i].noSeat).removeClass('seat-availiable');
            jQuery('#' + objData[i].noSeat).removeClass('selected');

        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("sorry, there was a problem!");
        console.log("error");
    },
    complete: function () {
        console.log("complete");
    }

});
```

}

it should be green automatically, because i only send number of seat booked from aspx and in .js I only change to red if noseat is equal of data I send from .aspx
but if I reload Index.html manually. the seat is change to green. it works but not automatically. I used to html refres meta tag, and reload on page_load, but it make the page blinking. I want it refresh without blinking.

Comment: use update panel, it'll be helpful

Comment: how can i use it ? i'm pretty new programmer @Codeek

Comment: @azalikaEriya your approcah is also good.

Comment: With ajax it is not possible ? i think using ajax without page load you can change the color of your booked seats.

Comment: please read explanation @ArunPrasanth
please anyone ?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response, wasn't here on terminal, what I meant was place the controls whose values are refreshed every 2 seconds  inside Update Panel which helps in asynchronus postback, (removing the blink part) and an timer control from AjaxExtensions. Read about Update Panel, this link will give you an idea what to do http://forums.asp.net/post/3281649.aspx

Comment: Thanks for help it's very kind of you, but I'll try another way, maybe I'll re-design my database and set a trigger. because I'm not familiar with C# yet and I'm under deadline till end of January @Codeek

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you control this changes just on client side instead of send data back to the server everytime?

By doing this, you avoid a lot of server requests every 2 seconds.

But, if you still want to follow your approach, I recommend you perform your ajax only when you change a seat (instead of all seats in your page). When you click in a seat and set the end time value, you can call your ajax telling the database that a specific seat is booked at that moment.

Other approach that I suggest you is: every time you get the result in your ajax call, you can set all seats in your page as "available"

```
(jQuery('your-common-seat-class').removeClass('seat-booked').addClass('seat-availiable');
```

and for each seat in your response data you set them as booked.

```
for (i = 0; i < objData.length; i++) {
    //console.log(objData[i].noSeat);
    jQuery('#' + objData[i].noSeat).addClass('seat-booked');
    jQuery('#class-' + objData[i].noSeat).attr('value', 'seat-booked');
}
```